# Can i open a modal window from file A and displaying file B on the modal window?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am studying the Jquery modal-form example :

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Is it possible to open a modal window from file A and displaying an existing file B on the modal window ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Are you talking about opening a modal and then loading the contents of that modal from a different file? I'm sure you could use the `open` event to then make a `.load()` or `.ajax()` call.

Comment: Yes i need the content from a diferent file just like using an iframe inside the modal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog_form"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#create-user').click(function() {
    $('#dialog_form').dialog(
    {
        open: function() {
            $(this).load('form_new.html');
        },
        modal: true
    }
    );
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: I try to add this code inside a call to a button click `$( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
                      
        $('#dialog-form').dialog({
   open: function() {
            $(this).load('form_new.html');
        },
   modal: true
  });

      });` The button now is not opening the modal, may it be some syntax error? sorry i am new to Jquery

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo Try this.

Comment: The only code who works to me was :       
    `$( "#create-user" )
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
          });`

Comment: I try to adapt your sugestion but did not open the modal window :

    ` $( "#create-user" ) 
      .button()
      .click(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function() {
            $(this).load("outro.html");
        }
    });

    $('#showDialog').click(function() {
        $("#dialog-form").open();
        return false;
    });
 });`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="showDialog">Show dialog</a>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").load("fileb.html").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    $('#showDialog').click(function() {
        $("#dialog").open();
        return false;
    });
});
```

If fileb.html is a full web page, you may want to append an iframe to `$("#dialog")` instead.  Additionally, you could do the append or the load in the open event of the dialog.

Alternate jQuery that uses the open event:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function() {
            $(this).load("fileb.html");
        }
    });

    $('#showDialog').click(function() {
        $("#dialog").open();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a way to target a filename that has been defined in the clickable link or button.. instead of having to define it in the scripting itself?
for example...
When a link has something like :

```
 <a href="#" class="CLICKCLASS" name="filename">click me</a>
```

The code to trigger the modal :

```
 $(function() {
      $(".CLICKCLASS").load("INFO_FROM_NAME_ATTRIBUTE").dialog({autoOpen: false});
      $('.CLICKCLASS').click(function() {
          $("#dialog").open();
          return false;
      });
  });
```

I don't know which attribute could be used for it, but this would make the script open to use in every link or button that needs to load a modal box